# Trouble with an onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm building a gallery and osm of the items will have multiple views - similar to items found in an etsy gallery - and I'm trying to figure out whats going wrong. I started this a while ago and it worked but as I'm not a coder (exclusively) and just teaching myself, I can't tell what has changed or what I'm missing.

The goal is to have a large image and three thumbnails. When one of the three thumbnails is selected it will replace the large image with the corresponding image.

The code:

Here is what I have as my js function I am linking in:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function altViews(next_img) {
        document.getElementById("big").src = next_img;
    }

</script>
```

*(Note, it is giving me an error on line 4 : document.getElementById("big").src = next_img;)*

Here is the code I used for the image and the thumbnails:

```
<div class="artwork">
    <img id="big" src="../images/_101111-1.png"/>
    <div class="gallery-thumbnails">
      <img class="gallery-thumb" src="images/_101111-1.jpg" onclick="altViews('../images/_101111-1.jpg')">
      <img class="gallery-thumb" src="images/_101111-3.jpg" onclick="altViews('../images/_101111-3.jpg')">
      <img class="gallery-thumb" src="images/_101111-4.jpg" onclick="altViews('../images/_101111-4.png')">
    </div>
    <div class="rule">
    </div>
  </div>
```

If there are any details I've left out, please let me know. Also, I am a novice with js and php and teaching myself in my spare time so this might be a simple solution but I'm not familiar enough with it yet to figure it out.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: in Dreamweaver I am getting "There is a syntax error on line 6"
(4 in the code above)

Comment: What happens when you run this code in a browser?

Comment: @JohnConde I had a friend take a look at the files and we found that I made one key error: when I extracted the script and made it into it's own new js file I kept the script tags in there causing it to not know what to do with a '>' it found (side note, I know know that Chrome has a Javascript Console. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close the `<img>` tag adding a backslash to the end `/>`

```
<img class="gallery-thumb" src="images/_101111-1.jpg" onclick="altViews('../images/_101111-1.jpg')"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still having the js issue but I completely missed that.

Comment: There are some error on your website `Uncaught ReferenceError: altViews is not defined`

Comment: I had a friend take a look at the files and we found that I made one key error: when I extracted the script and made it into it's own new js file I kept the script tags in there causing it to not know what to do with a '>' it found (side note, I know know that Chrome has a Javascript Console. Thanks for your help